# How to update a part of torch.nn.Parameter

Tags: parameters, pytorch, freeze, updating, leaf

**For updating a part of parameters defined by torch.nn.Parameter. I have tested the following three ways, but only one works.**

#(1)

```
import torch
class NET(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NET, self).__init__()
        self.params = torch.ones(4)
        self.P = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1))
        self.params[1] = self.P
    def forward(self, x):
        y = x * self.params
        return y.sum()

net = NET()
x = torch.rand(4)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
for _ in range(10):
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss = net(x)
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

**# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time**

#(2)

```
import torch
class NET(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NET, self).__init__()
        self.P = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1))
    def forward(self, x):
        params = torch.ones(4)
        params[1] = self.P
        y = x * params
        return y.sum()

net = NET()
x = torch.rand(4)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
for _ in range(10):
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss = net(x)
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

**# It works, but the operations of Create and Assign are needed in each forward.**

#(3)

```
import torch
class NET(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NET, self).__init__()
        self.params = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(4))
    def forward(self, x):
        y = x * self.params
        return y.sum()

net = NET()
net.params[1].requires_grad = False
x = torch.rand(4)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
for _ in range(10):
    optim.zero_grad()
    loss = net(x)
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

**# RuntimeError: you can only change requires_grad flags of leaf variables.**

**I wonder how to update a part of parameters in the ways (1) and (3).**

Answer (score 1):

A small note on the use of `requires_grad` and [nn.Parameter](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html):

1. If you had to freeze a sub-module of you [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html), you would require the use of [`requires_grad_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad_.html). However, you cannot partially require gradients on a tensor.
2. A `nn.Parameter` is a wrapper which allows a given `torch.Tensor` to be ***registered*** inside a `nn.Module`. By default, the wrapped tensor will require gradient computation.

You must therefore absolutely have your parameter tensor defined as:

```
nn.Parameter(torch.ones(4))
```

And not as:

```
self.params = torch.ones(4)
```

Ultimately you should check the content of your registered parameters with [`nn.Module#parameters`](https://nn.Module#parameters) before loading them inside an optimizer.

Your first code `#1` crashes because you are performing multiple backpropagations on the same tree without explicitly setting the [`retain_graph`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#graph-retaining) to `True`. The following process works fine:

```
for _ in range(10):
    optim.zero_grad()
    x = torch.rand(4) # new x
    loss = net(x)
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

Your second code `#2` is correct because you are assigning the tensor which requires gradient to a different tensor. A minimal implementation to check that the gradient is indeed computed on `P` is as follows:

```
# reassign parameter tensor to bigger tensor
>>> P = torch.ones(1, requires_grad=True)
>>> params = torch.ones(4)
>>> params[1] = P

# inference and backpropagation
>>> (torch.rand(4)*params).sum().backward()
>>> P.grad
tensor([0.46701658])
```

Your third code `#3` is invalid because you are requiring gradient computation on part of the code which is not possible:

```
net.params[1].requires_grad = False # invalid
```

---

An alternative way to do it instead is by masking the gradient after the back propagation has been done on the parameters:

```
class NET(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.params = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(4))

    def forward(self, x):
        y = x * self.params
        return y.sum()


net = NET()
net(torch.rand(4)).backward()
net.params.grad[1] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While, the error still seems to exsit according to your revised #1 code.